reading address represented by pointer member of vec
A vec has three members: length, capacity and a pointer to heap memory.
vec provides methods len and capacity to rad those values, but no such method for pointer value.
Is it anyway possible to address value pointer holds?

There are in fact two methods to retrieve the managed pointer value:

Vec::as_ptr
Vec::as_mut_ptr


You can also use as_slice / as_mut_slice and read that, as the slice reference is a pointer to the start of the buffer.
